# Why Winforms.Button.Text works for DataBinding but not ImageKey?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, data-binding

Is there anyone who knows this?

I have been trying this for the last week, and no luck.

Now I can see that once can bind successfully to a Button's Text property, but not its ImageKey property:

```
myButton.Text = "new text"; // really changes the bound data
myButton.ImageKey = "new text"; // does NOT change the bound data
```

I use:

```
myButton.DataBindings.Add ( new Binding ( "ImageKey", this.MyData, "Name", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged ) );
```

Why? What makes the Binding tick/work? I just don't get it.

EDIT:

OK so I defined these for my own derived control:

```
public event EventHandler ImageKeyChanged;

protected virtual void OnImageKeyChanged ( EventArgs e )
{
    if ( ImageKeyChanged!= null )
    {
        ImageKeyChanged ( this, e );
    }
}

[Bindable ( true )]
public new string ImageKey
{
    get
    {
        return base.ImageKey;
    }
    set
    {
        base.ImageKey = value;
        this.OnImageKeyChanged ( EventArgs.Empty );
    }
}
```

It still doesn't work. Is there a tutorial or something on the net, that shows this. It just doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ...does NOT change the bound data

for 2-way binding, you need notification events - this can take 2 common forms:

- a `public event EventHandler {name}Changed;`, where `{name}` is the bound property (`ImageKeyChanged`, for example)
- the object can implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`

This is certainly how object-to-control binding works; I'm pretty sure that control-to-object detection is very similar. Note that there is a `TextChanged` event, but no `ImageKeyChanged` event.

Comment: Thanks Marc. I implemented the event, and also had the INotifyPropertyChanged for the object that's bound before. But still the same. I must be missing something.

Comment: Actually I think it worked. I always have this at the end of the day, will check for another property.

Comment: Ok it seems like another property I added other than ImageKey doesn't work. Do you know why this might be? So I bind ImageKey to Name, and it worked after I did your changes. But now I wrote exactly the same code for another property (without new, as this property doesn't exist in the base), but now the same bound data property doesn't change.

Comment: Nevermind I think I got it working with these suggestions. Sorry it's my bad, but it's you and Lucero's replies that helped me out.

Answer (score 2):

For bindings to work, the class with the property to be bound needs to supply change events (`TextChanged` for the `Text` property for instance) or implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`. Since the `Button` class doesn't supply a `ImageKeyChanged` event, the binding cannot subscribe to get notified of the change.

Comment: Thanks Lucero, I think I got it working. Thanks to you and Marc. I want to accept both answers.